# How to adjust background image to content without loosing part of image (no background-size: cover)

Tags: html, css, svg

It's probably a very specific problem related to the design I have to integrate but I have a  notebook background image, and inside another  where I load dynamic content (text only) that comes from DB. I'd like to adjust size of notebook image so when content text grows, the background image grows as well but without stretching the image or loosing part of the image, which happens when one use `background-size: cover`. I made a snippet bellow that might express better my problem. I don't know if I can solve it with CSS only, if there's an svg trick, or if it just can't be.

```css
.container {
}

.notebook {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  width: 60%;
  background-image: url("https://wip.bruce.work/guests/collections/picture/svg/spiral-bound-notebook.svg");
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

.textElement {
  width: 40%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-right: 5%;
  font-size: .8rem
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="notebook">
    <div class="textElement">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe this is useful https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: @Ingus this is actually a `background-size: cover` solution which cannot work for me :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An idea for such background is to have 3 parts. A top and bottom part that will not repeat and a middle part with a pattern that will repeat.

Here is a basic (not perfect) attempt where I used vh unit. Resize the browser to see the effect. You simply need to find how to correctly split and repeat your background:

```css
body {
 margin:0;
 background:#000;
}
.notepad {
  position:relative;
  margin:100px;
  width:500px;
  min-height:50vh;
  background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6mjc.png) center/100% auto;
}
.notepad:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute; 
  top:-100px;
  bottom:100%;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/rg7O8.png) bottom/100% auto no-repeat;
}
.notepad:after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute; 
  top:100%;
  bottom:-50px;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/B93KI.png) top/100% auto no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="notepad">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I see there are a lot of answers. This is my atempt. I'm moving the SVG inline and I'm putting the text inside a `<textPath>` element and I'm using `textLength="6080" lengthAdjust="spacing"` for the `<textPath>` where `6080` is the length of the path. However if your text length is varying a lot, this won't do. Also if the text is very long the text may become unreadable.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="976" height="395" viewBox="0 0 976 395">
    <defs>
        <path id="a" stroke="red" d="M394.085 0a100 100 0 0 0 1.667 22.757l2.675 14.106a48.927 48.927 0 0 0 38.953 38.952l14.106 2.676a100 100 0 0 0 37.271 0l14.106-2.676a48.927 48.927 0 0 0 38.952-38.952l2.676-14.106A100 100 0 0 0 546.158 0H917c12.703 0 23 10.297 23 23v315c0 12.703-10.297 23-23 23H23c-12.703 0-23-10.297-23-23V23C0 10.297 10.297 0 23 0h371.085zM15 63a5 5 0 1 0 0-10 5 5 0 0 0 0 10zm0 50a5 5 0 1 0 0-10 5 5 0 0 0 0 10zm0 50a5 5 0 1 0 0-10 5 5 0 0 0 0 10zm0 50a5 5 0 1 0 0-10 5 5 0 0 0 0 10zm0 50a5 5 0 1 0 0-10 5 5 0 0 0 0 10zm0 50a5 5 0 1 0 0-10 5 5 0 0 0 0 10z"/>

    </defs>
    <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <g transform="translate(19 9)">
            <use fill="#FFc" xlink:href="#a"/>
            <path fill="#ccc" d="M0 0h30v361H0z" />
        </g>
        <g stroke="black" stroke-width="3" transform="translate(2 53)">
            <path d="M32 13c0 7.18-7.163 13-16 13S0 20.18 0 13 7.163 0 16 0M32 63c0 7.18-7.163 13-16 13S0 70.18 0 63s7.163-13 16-13M32 113c0 7.18-7.163 13-16 13s-16-5.82-16-13 7.163-13 16-13M32 163c0 7.18-7.163 13-16 13s-16-5.82-16-13 7.163-13 16-13M32 213c0 7.18-7.163 13-16 13s-16-5.82-16-13 7.163-13 16-13M32 263c0 7.18-7.163 13-16 13s-16-5.82-16-13 7.163-13 16-13"/>
        </g>
        <path fill="#D6D6D6" d="M489 123h1v219h-1z"/>
        
        <path stroke="#d9d9d9" d="M70,50H400
                               M70,70H400
                               M70,90H420
                               M70,110H460
                               M70,130H460
                               M70,150H460
                               M70,170H460
                               M70,190H460
                               M70,210H460
                               M70,230H460
                               M70,250H460
                               M70,270H460
                               M70,290H460
                               M70,310H460
                               M70,330H460
                               M70,350H460" id="txt"/>
      
    </g>
    
    
     <text stroke="#000000" font-size="11" >
      <textPath xlink:href="#txt" textLength="6080" lengthAdjust="spacing">
        <tspan >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
        
        iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur********</tspan>
      </textPath> 
     </text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you show us the desired effect ? I do not understand what the border in the middle does since your content is not separated in two different columns.

On another note, your "spiral-bound-notebook.svg" image is quite easy to replicate using CSS and background images (or even using only CSS if you).

First apply a white background and a box-shadow equivalent to the one you are using on your image to your content container.

```
.container {
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px  rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    border-radius: 1em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Regarding the notebook holes, I would create a pattern and have it repeat along the left edge of your content container as a background image with a padding-left equivalent to the pattern width like so.

```
.textElement {
    padding-left: 3em;
    background-image: url(https://wip.bruce.work/guests/collections/picture/svg/spiral-bound-notebook.svg);
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    background-size: 50%;
}
```

Here is an updated version of your pen to give you an idea :
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yQWwga

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the fact that the top and bottom of that particular image which you use prevent a continuous spiral-binding graphic (since the "spiral" doesn't go from top to bottom, but is in the middle part), you can combine a `background-size` of `100% auto` (for the full width) and `repeat-y` to achive a vertical repetition of the image while stretching it across the full width of the container.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Mzdxvp